Bounding $N$ from below to simplfy $\epsilon-N$ proofs simply
When we do the epsilon delta proof for even the simplest of functions, it is a crucial step to restrict $\delta$ in some set of values before we give  the actual value of delta  example.
I want to make an analogous result for limit of discrete sequences. Let me show a simple example where we could use that. Suppose we want to prove that $\{\frac{1}{2n+3}\}_n$ converges to $0$. We can prove this in the following way: $\frac{1}{2n+3} <_{(1)} \frac{1}{2n+n}.$ This simplification is justified if $n>3$.
If we are provided that $\{\frac{1}{n}\} $ converges to $0$, then there exist some $\tilde{n}$ such that for $n >\tilde{n}$ , we have $\frac{1}{n} < 3 \epsilon$. Now, clearly any number in the set $\{n | n> \tilde{n} \}$ would satisfy this too. If we have that the intersection $\{n | n> \tilde{n} \} \cap \{ n | n>3\}$ (1) is non empty, we take some $n'$ out of it's intersection and we can chain the inequalities to get: $ \frac{1}{2n+3} < \frac{1}{3n } <\epsilon$.
And this $n'$ we claim then is the required for the $\epsilon-N$ definition for $\frac{1}{2n+3}$.
This trick I mentioned above is used quite often in many problems, but I have never seen justification as to why  the intersection (1) is not empty. I am presuming it comes from the fact that both the sets are unbounded from above. Now, I don't know how to prove that either. In particular, I think it'd be a bit difficult to prove from the information I got from this post .  Maybe it'd be easy to prove unboundedness of rays in $\mathbb{N}$ when we have that $\mathbb{N}$ itself is unbounded. Or it could be that I am on completely the wrong track.
How do I prove rigorously that the intersection (1) is non empty?

"unbounded from above" is not enough. E.g. "even numbers >10" and "odd numbers >42" have empty intersection

If $A:=\{n | n> a \}$ and $B:=\{ n | n>b\}$ then one must be a subset of the other (depending on whether $a$ or $b$ is larger). Proving it is near trivial. Therefore the intersection is never empty and is in fact an infinite set.

It may be helpful to learn about the notion "almost all $n$". We say that a statement $\Phi(n)$ holds for almost all natural numbers $n$ if there are only finitely many $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\Phi(n)$ is false.
This frees your mind from needing to remember if $\Phi(n)$ holds for all $n>7$  or for all $n>42$ or whatnot. (Note however: "holds for all even $n$" is not for almost all; "holds for all non-prime $n$" is not for almost all).
Now if $\Phi(n)$ holds for almost all $n$ and $\Psi(n)$ holds for almost all $n$, then $\Phi(n)\land\Psi(n)$ hoilds for almost all $n$ (why?)
Note that $a_n\to a$ can then be expressed as: For all $\epsilon >0$, for almost all natural numbers $n$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$.
As (for given $\epsilon$), you want to show an "almost all"-statement, you are free to add (finitely many) additional "almost all"-conditions along the way without harm.
This may sound less formal, but once you verified the required properties (e.g., what I wrote about $\Phi(n)\land\Psi(n)$), things are fully justified.
One final warning, however: You may encounter the notion of "almost all" in different contexts with different meanings. "All but finitely many" is well-suited for the context of natural numebrs (or perhaps integers or rational numbers). But you may also encounter it to mean "all but countabley many" (in the context of uncountable sets such as $\mathbb R", or "all but a set of measure zero" once you learn about measure theory.
